# Create a new column by combining values with the same index in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column by `groupby` existing columns and `join`its values.

For example, the original data frame(df) looks like:

```
index  col1 col2 col3
0      bar   tic   A
1      bar   tac   B
2      far   toe   C
3      far   toe   D
```

Then, if `col1` and `col2` exactly matches, I want to join values in `col3` with '-' to create col4.
The desired format would be:

```
index  col1 col2 col3 col4
0      bar  tic    A    A
1      bar  tac    B    B
2      far  toe    C   C-D
3      far  toe    D   C-D
```

I used below code but didn't get the desired result and get warning message of "UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name"
What should I do?

```
import pandas as pd

df.col4 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x))
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GroupBy.transform`:

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('-'.join)

  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  bar  tic    A    A
1  bar  tac    B    B
2  far  toe    C  C-D
3  far  toe    D  C-D
```

---

If you want to aggregate the rows, use `GroupBy.apply` chained with `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].agg('-'.join).reset_index()

  col1 col2 col3
0  bar  tac    B
1  bar  tic    A
2  far  toe  C-D
```